# How to make mega menu occupied full page width?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to make the mega menu occupied the full page width.
I have almost tried everything that I can thing about.

[Link to testing site](http://13.127.5.70/shop/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's your container that is dictating the width of your Mega Menu. You need to make it separate from its parent div.

Add this in your theme's custom CSS or child theme CSS

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) /* You might have to add the code for other screen sizes too depending on your theme */
.sf-menu .megamenu .megamenu_wrap {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) /* You might have to add the code for other screen sizes too depending on your theme */
.sf-menu .megamenu .megamenu_wrap {
   left: 0;
}

/* Use !important where necessary if the changes do not reflect on your site. Refrain from using it unless absolutely necessary. */
```

Hope this helps. I have tested the code above on your test site using Inspect in Chrome.

Always remember, only edit your child theme or custom CSS box provided in your theme. Never the core theme.

Comment: !important isn't working.
I am happy with the resolution.
I am going to edit the css file directly as it's ignoring !important & custom css

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, then your problem is the alignment of the mega menu, if you set your mega menu to 100vw, then it will be aligned to the right.

This happens because of your div.lm-col-12, which have

position: relative;

The position relative will force any position used in any child element to have their root position from that position.

Try to avoid that specific position relative declaration. Try setting position for the class to **static** instead.